# Set default syntax highlighting for file extension in gedit

Tags: gedit

I am working on octave scripts which have the file name extension .m. When I open them, gedit chooses Objective-C as default syntax highlight option, so I have to change that manually every time.
How can I change the default syntax highlighting option for files ending on .m to octave permanently?